# Meaning of Powershell statement

Tags: powershell

I am completely new to Powershell and I am trying to understand what this fragment of code does:

```
$OwnFunctionsDir = "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Functions"
Write-Host "Loading own PowerShell functions from:" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "$OwnFunctionsDir" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Get-ChildItem "$OwnFunctionsDir\*.ps1" | %{.$_}
Write-Host ''
```

In particular I cannot interpret what the line `Get-Children …` does. This code is intended to be added to your Powershell profile to load commonly used functions at Powershell startup.

Comment: `Get-Help Get-ChildItem` doesn't help (pun intended)?

Comment: the `%` is an alias for `ForEach-Object`, the `. $_` is "dot sourcing" every `.ps1` file that `Get-ChildItem` found into the current session. take a look at this >> Source - PowerShell - SS64.com — https://ss64.com/ps/source.html

Comment: @Jonathan: This should not be under SO, it might go to Code Review. But Since you are new to PS, just a suggestion would be to read thoroughly about PS in get-help section for all the cmdlets followed by the documents available on internet. SO is a forum where people post Codes on which they struggle to fix. In your case, it is just an opinion based. Also, to answer your question, that is not `get-children`; it is `get-childitem` which basically pulls the list of files and folders similar to `dir` command in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer

This command loads the contents of all ".ps1" files in "<yourHomeDirecotry>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Functions" into your working session.

## Long Answer

First, `$env:USERPROFILE` is an environment variable that corresponds to your home directory. So in my case it is "c:\users\jboyd"

The first interesting bit of code is:

```
$OwnFunctionsDir = "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Functions"
```

This assigns a string to a new variable named `OwnFunctionsDir`. What's interesting about this string is that it is double quoted and it contains the variable `$env:USERPROFILE`. PowerShell expands variables in double quoted strings (this is not the case for single quoted strings). So if this were running on my machine the value of `$OwnFunctionsDir` would be "c:\users\jboyd\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Functions".

Skipping the `Write-host` functions (because I think they are pretty self explanatory) takes us to:

```
Get-ChildItem "$OwnFunctionsDir\*.ps1" | %{.$_}
```

`Get-ChildItem` is interesting because its behavior depends on the PowerShell provider (don't worry about what that is) but in this case `Get-ChildItem` is the equivalent of `dir` or `ls`. `$OwnFunctionsDir\*.ps1` is the path being enumerated. Using my machine as an example, this is equivalent to listing all files with names matching the wildcard pattern "*.ps1" (essentially all PowerShell files) in the directory "c:\users\jboyd\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Functions".

The `|` character pipes the results of the command on the left to the command on the right.

The `%` character is an alias for the `ForEach-Object` command. The left and right curly braces are a scriptblock, this is the body of the foreach command. So each item from `Get-ChildItem` is piped into the scriptblock.

In the scriptblock of the `ForEach-Object` command the `$_` variable represents the current item being processed. In this case `$_` will be a PowerShell file with an extension ".ps1". When we invoke a PowerShell file with a period in front of it that is called dot sourcing. Dot sourcing loads the content of a file into your working session. So any variables or functions in the file are loaded.